# Getting no results after parsing X12 834 file using x12Parser

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, edi, x12

I am banging my head from 2 days. I am using x12 Parser, OOPsfactory for parsing a x12n 834 file. I need to parse each and every member eligibility information from this file. However, I was able to convert them to xml file. I used every steps as described in [Convert XML TO CSV OOPsFactory](https://x12parser.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Creating%20a%20flat%20file%20from%20the%20X12%20xml%20using%20XSLT%20and%20XslCompiledTransform)!

My code for transforming the file is:

```
    Stream _EligFileStream = new FileStream("E:\\Test\\a.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    EligibilityTransformationService _EligibilityTransformationService = new EligibilityTransformationService();
    EligibilityBenefitDocument _EligibilityBenefitDocument = _EligibilityTransformationService.Transform271ToBenefitResponse(_EligFileStream);
    List<EligibilityBenefitResponse> _EligibilityBenefitResponsesList = new List<EligibilityBenefitResponse>();
    _EligibilityBenefitResponsesList = _EligibilityBenefitDocument.EligibilityBenefitResponses;
    foreach (EligibilityBenefitResponse _EligibilityBenefitInquiry in _EligibilityBenefitResponsesList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_EligibilityBenefitInquiry.Dependent.Name);
        /*
        ....
        ....
        other required fields
        */
    }
    Console.Read();
```

The transformationcode of OopsFactory is returning me zero results. What am I doing wrong.

Does anyone has face the same problem before or had succeeded in parsing the 834 eligibility file using OopsFactory with any other free tool.

Here is my sample source file:

```
ISA*00*XXX       *00*XXX       *ZZ*1234           *30*11-1111111     *120101*1200*^*00501*000000001*0*T*:
GS*BE*ABC AB12*1234*201
40909*1200*1*X*005010X220A1
ST*834*888999*005010X220A1
BGN*00*000315*20120101*1200****2
DTP*202*D8*20141001
QTY*TO*99999
N1*P5*LOC
AL AB12*FI*123456789
N1*IN*ABCCARE*FI*11-1111111
```

I am using the transformation file from Oopsfactory package, which was itself in the Oopsfactory code base. Here's the link to the Oopsfactory xslt file:
[XSLT File Link](http://x12parser.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/src/OopFactory.X12.Hipaa/Eligibility/Services/Xsl/X12-271-To-BenefitResponse.xslt)!

Comment: Can you share your source EDI file?  You might want to obfuscate some details first.....

Comment: You should also post your XSLT transformation so we can see how that is written.

Comment: @Andrew I updated the question. Please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: @Andrew I used Oopsfactory for writing my own parser for 837 files. It has a very good design and coding was very easy. I thought, Oopsfactory is also able to parse 834 files as it had supported class and models. I hope I am right.

Comment: I'm assuming you've seen this link: http://x12parser.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Parsing%20an%20834%20Transaction&referringTitle=Documentation where it parses it to a generic XML format.  I think you're using code based on the 271 document type.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I Google a lot about the difference between the 834 file, 270, 271 , x12n 834 file but till now had found nothing. Is the above sample file I posted actually x12n 834 file? I am also not pretty sure about that. Also, I have some files with ~ sign at the end and some not. Whats the difference. Could you please provide me some link.

Comment: The file you have is an 834.  You can tell by the ST segment.  That will specify transaction type.  The character at the end of each segment is called the segment terminator.  This can vary by trading partner.  It is arbitrarily assigned. Tilde is very common though.  Why not use commercial translation software to make your life easier?